# Get value of the object by attribute value

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath

I'm stuck a little at this point.
Let's say, we have this XML:

```
<object>
    <data name="my name">Alex</data>
    <data name="somebody's name">Dan</data>
</object>
```

In PHP, I can select value of the object by simplexml's XPath:

```
<?
$result = $xml->xpath('/object/data[@name="my name"]'); //array of values
echo $result[0]; //output: Alex
?>
```

But I can't get it: how can I do the same using javascript? I mean, is there any method like .getElementByTagName(), but for attribute's value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

`$("data[name='my name']")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector`

```
var result = document.QuerySelector('data[name="my name"]');
console.log(result);
```

If there can be multiple matching elements, use `querySelectorAll`; it will return a `NodeList` that you can iterate over and index.